# Matplotlib animation faster first time it runs

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a Matplotlib animation embedded in Tkinter, and to control some aspects of the plot (e.g. plot limits) I have methods that stop the animation, make the requested changes and start it again. I noticed that every time I stop and re-run the animation it is slower than the first time (but not increasingly slower).

I observe the same with simpler animations (code below) when running from an IPython session:

First time run:

```
In [279]: run test
145.5 FPS    0 frames
104.0 FPS   25 frames
174.8 FPS   50 frames
184.1 FPS   75 frames
180.4 FPS  100 frames
184.1 FPS  125 frames
```

Second time run:

```
In [280]: run test

In [281]: 
123.7 FPS   0 frames
38.0 FPS   25 frames
37.8 FPS   50 frames
38.1 FPS   75 frames
38.1 FPS  100 frames
37.5 FPS  125 frames
```

This is the animation code used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import time

def setFig():
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    fig.clear()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    line = ax.plot([], [])
    return fig, ax, line

def init():
    line[0].set_data([], [])
    return line

def animate(i):
    line[0].set_data(range(100), np.random.random(100))
    if i % 25 == 0:
        global t_old
        t_new = time.time()
        print('{:5.1f} FPS{:>5d} frames'.format(25 / (t_new - t_old), i))
        t_old = t_new
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_old = time.time()
    fig, ax, line = setFig()
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, 
                                blit=True, interval=1, frames=150,
                                repeat=False)
    plt.show()
```

Notice that I set the animation interval to 1 millisecond. If I set it to zero this behaviour is not observed and all subsequent runs perform equally well, and the same happens if I close the figure before the second run. Why does this happen and how could I make sure subsequent animations run as fast as the first one?

Comment: This might be a better question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IanAuld I disagree, this seems like a reasonable question for SO.